# Api call using ajax on admin page returns invalid form key

Tags: magento2.3, admin, ajax

i'm trying to do an api call using ajax on admin page, but it keeps returning "Invalid form key"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery"
], function ($){

    let url = window.location.href;
    url = url.split('/');
    url = url.slice(2,4);
    url = url.join('/');

    console.log("URL -> "+(url+"/rest/V1/orders"));


    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url+"/rest/V1/orders",
            data: {
                "entity":{
                    "entity_id": <?php echo $order_id; ?>,
                    "status":"processing",
                    "state":"processing"
                }
            },
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer "+ '" + <?php echo $token; ?> + "'
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Tried this way, but also didn't work.

```
<script>
             var settings = {
             // "url": "http://"+url+"/rest/V1/orders",
             "url": url+"/rest/V1/orders",
             "method": "POST",
             "timeout": 0,
             "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Authorization": "Bearer "+token
             },
             "data": JSON.stringify(
                 {
                     "entity":{
                         "entity_id": order_id,
                         "status":"processing",
                         "state":"processing"
                     }
                 }
             ),
           };
           jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
             console.log(response);
           });
```

**update**
So i found out that, the token string parse was wrong, i fixed it, but know my problem is other, its returning Bad Request, Decoding error: \nUnable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error...

So i created another question: [Ajax api call returning Bad Request decoding error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350807/ajax-api-call-returning-bad-request-decoding-error)

Comment: Did you checked the ajax by calling a simple controller?

Comment: @Mehran, no i didn't, how could i check it ?

Comment: Are you in phtml file or in js file?

Comment: @Mehran, phtml file.

Comment: Instead of Window.location.href get the base url by this way $block->getBaseUrl(); and then check. or $block->getUrl('rest/V1/orders') .

Comment: @Mehran Tried both ways, but it didn't works, it returns 401 (Unauthorized) using $block->getUrl('rest/V1/orders'). And returns the page html using $block->getBaseUrl();

Comment: @RafaelFagundes can you please post your solution for " invalid form key"?

Comment: @MageDev it was a wrong string parse, a missing < " > OR extra < " >. I added an update on the final of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this will help you but try passing `form_key: window.FORM_KEY` in your data part

Thanks

Comment: It returns the same error: "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Comment: Try using this "Magento\Backend\App\Action​" as your ajax controller extends

Answer (score 0):

You need to add form_key to the data you upload
data:

```
{
                     ""form_key"": window.FORM_KEY
                ""entity"":{
                    ""entity_id"": <?php echo $order_id; ?>,
                    ""status"":""processing"",
                    ""state"":""processing""
                }
            },
```